# Question on function notation. Is this correct?

Tags: functions

$f$ is the function $f(x)=2x+5$

a) Find $f(3)$

I know that this is 
$2(3)+5=11$

Express the inverse function $f^{-1}$ in the form $f^{-1}(x)=$

I dont know how to do this.

Then the question goes on to say

$g$ is the function of $g(x)=x^2-25$

c)find $g(-3)=-3^2-25=-34$

then it asks find $gf(x)$. Give your answer as simply as possible.

I did $11+(-34)=-23$ (I'm not sure if this is the correct way of solving this)

Then it says solve $gf(x)=0$

So I solved both equations...

$2x+5=0$

and

$x^2-25=0$

And I got $-2.5$ and $5$. I then added them up and got $2.5$ as the final answer.
Is this correct?

Comment: No that's mostly incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=2x+5\\
\implies x=\dfrac{f(x)-5}{2}\\
\implies f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{x-5}{2}$$
And also
$$g(f(x))=(f(x))^2-25=4x^2+25+20x-25=4x^2+20x\\
g(f(x))=0\\
\implies 4x^2+20x=0\\
\implies x=0,-5$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in finding $f(3)$--just substitute $3$ where you see $x$.  To find the inverse, you need to use the definition of the inverse.  Some people write the function as $y = f(x)$ and then swap $x$ and $y$, i.e. $x = f(y)$ then solve for $y$ to find the inverse--that's fine, you can do that if it makes more sense, but it's basically the same as just using the definition of the inverse (which you may not realize if you don't do it this way):

$$
f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right) = x
$$

Now plug $f^{-1}(x)$ into $f(x)$:

\begin{align}
f\left((f^{-1}(x)\right) = 2\cdot\left((f^{-1}(x)\right) + 5 = x && \text{subtract }5\text{ from both sides}\\
2\cdot f^{-1}(x) = x - 5 && \text{divide both sides by } 2 \\
f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x - 5}{2}
\end{align}

To find $g\left((f(x)\right)$ (or $g\circ f$), again, just plug in $f(x)$ into $g(x)$ just as you substituted $3$ into $f(x)$ and $-3$ into $g(x)$--it's just now you are plugging in a large expression involving $x$ instead of just a single number:

\begin{align}
g(x) = (\ )^2 - 25 && \text{plug } f(x) \text{ into ( ) for }g(x) \\
g\left(f(x)\right) = \left(f(x)\right)^2 - 25 && \text{plug in }2x + 5\text{ for } f(x) \\
g\left(f(x)\right) = (2x + 5)^2 - 25 && \text{solve equation }g\left(f(x)\right) = 0 \\
0 = (2x + 5)^2 - 25 && \text{this is a difference of squares (or isolate the squared term)} \\
(2x + 5)^2 = 25 && \text{take square root--don't forget }\pm \\
2x + 5 = \pm\sqrt{25} = \pm 5 && \text{solve for x} \\
x = \frac{\pm5 - 5}{2} = 5\frac{-1 \pm 1}{2} && x \text{ can equal }either\text{ of those}\\
x = 0 \text{ or } x = -5
\end{align}